# Obtaining an attached object from unattached one in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Let's say I have several types of entities in a JPA application, and a Repository which does all database-related operations.

Sometimes it's passed unattached entities from outside, and I want to get an attached copy of them 
(for example, to persist new entities which contain a reference to this one, or to access lazy properties).

`EntityManager.refresh(entity)` doesn't work on unattached objects. `EntityManager.merge(entity)` will copy the current state of detaching entity instead of getting current values from database, as I want. `EntityManager.find(entity.getId(), entityClass)` works, and that's what I do now, but it depends on the type of entity (though now that I think of it, `EntityManager.find(entity.getId(), entity.getClass())` is better). Are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge and refresh: 
`entityManager.refresh(entityManager.merge(entity));`

`merge` will give you a managed entity, then you can use `refresh` to get the values from DB.

This code should work on both attached and detached entities.